# Display Visual Studio Team Services Release Name within web app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, alm

I'm deploying a web app to Azure using Visual Studio Team Services to build and then release.

During release I'm replacing tokens within the `web.config` file with environment variables I have setup within the release definition for each environment, staging, production etc.

I have set the **Release Name Format** to include the build number and release number using the following:

```
$(Build.BuildNumber).$(rev:r)
```

I know `Release.ReleaseName` is provided as a pre-defined global release variable, but how can I access this `Release.ReleaseName` variable within my app to display it in a footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can use [Tokenization build / release task](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Tokenization) to transfer the value of a variable into web.config file.

But since the variable you want to use is filled with the value of another variable, you need to add an additional powershell step to do this.

Following are the steps for you reference:

1. Create a new variable.
   [image]
2. Change the content that you want to replace in web.config to **__Eddie__**.
3. Add a powershell step to set the value of "Eddie" to "Release.ReleaseName".
   [image]
4. Add a Tokenization step to replace the **__Eddie__** in config.
   [image]

Now, when you start the release, the content in web.config will be replaced by the value of Release.ReleaseName.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up doing it in a slightly different way. I deployed a separate powershell script as part of my build which does a simple find and replace on the web.config. I'm running that using the PowerShell task and passing in the token, Release.ReleaseName variable and path to the web.config file. I then run my other Tokenization task for all the other variables. I think that your solution is much cleaner, so I will probably switch to that.